# how can I use the string separators method in C# to remove paragraph symbols from a text file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the string separator method to remove paragraph symbols from a text file.

I've done several google searches but haven't gotten this to work.
I've tried `"\xB6"`, `"\x U+2029"`, and several derivatives but to no success.

Here is the line I've been using:

```
string[] separators = { ",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", " ", "-", "#", "  ", "   ", "\r", "\t", "\f", "\xB6" };
```

I would really appreciate your help. If you'd be kind enough to include a short sample with your answer this would help me tremendously; because, as a beginner I tend to trip up frequently with syntax.

P.S. If you have any good referential links to share regarding C# and text parsing I promise you a large land grant after I've taken over the world by text parsing.

Comment: Do you have some code that doesn't work or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried "\u2029"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf.aspx

Comment: So far all you've done is declare an array variable and put some strings in it. What are you trying to actually do with that array of strings that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hex viewer to see what character code these paragraph separators are.  Then you will know what to filter on.